How to create test automation report by fetching data from postgresql
looking what is the best way to represent test results in visualization (with graphs, tables, history of the test script results ) by fetching data from postgres. Postgres db contains all test results , metadata, dates). Which simple technology or tools need to be used.


Set Up the Environment
Ensure you have Python installed, along with the necessary libraries.
Install the required packages:
pip install psycopg2 pandas jinja2

Connect to PostgreSQL Database
Use psycopg2 to connect to your PostgreSQL database and fetch the test data.
import psycopg2
def fetch_test_data():
try:
# Establish connection
connection = psycopg2.connect(
user="your_username",
password="your_password",
host="your_host",
port="your_port",
database="your_database"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
     # Execute the query
     query = "SELECT * FROM test_results;"  # Replace with your query
     cursor.execute(query)

     # Fetch all the rows
     test_data = cursor.fetchall()

     # Optionally, fetch column names if needed
     column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

     return test_data, column_names

 except Exception as error:
     print(f"Error fetching data: {error}")
 finally:
     if connection:
         cursor.close()
         connection.close()


Process Data with Pandas
Use pandas to manipulate and organize the data for reporting.
import pandas as pd
def process_data(test_data, column_names):
# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=column_names)
 # Example: Calculate summary statistics
 summary = df.describe()

 return df, summary


Generate the Report
Use jinja2 to create an HTML report or matplotlib for graphs and visualizations.
from jinja2 import Template
def generate_html_report(df, summary):
# Load your HTML template
html_template = """

Test Automation Report

Test Automation Report
Summary
{{ summary }}
Test Details
{{ df.to_html(index=False) }}


"""
 template = Template(html_template)
 report = template.render(df=df, summary=summary)

 with open("test_automation_report.html", "w") as file:
     file.write(report)


Integrate and Execute
Integrate the functions to fetch the data, process it, and generate the report.
if name == "main":
test_data, column_names = fetch_test_data()
df, summary = process_data(test_data, column_names)
generate_html_report(df, summary)

Automate and Schedule (Optional)
You can automate this process by scheduling it with a task scheduler (e.g., cron on Linux or Task Scheduler on Windows).

Advanced Reporting
For more advanced reports, you might want to include charts and graphs. You can use libraries like matplotlib or seaborn for visualization.
If you prefer a PDF report, consider using WeasyPrint or ReportLab to convert HTML to PDF.
Example Report Generation:
After running the script, you’ll have an HTML file (test_automation_report.html) that contains your test automation report, which can be viewed in any web browser.


This approach is flexible and can be customized based on the structure of your test data and the specific details you want in your report.
